# sed to delete specific lines from a file using bash script

Tags: bash, sed

I have the command to delete specific lines from a file, e.g. the one below would delete lines 2 to 1000 from a file called large_file.csv

```
sed -i -e 2,1000d large_file.csv
```

But I am writing a bash script that has the number 1000 being calculated dynamically using a formula and stored in a variable **$rows_per_file**, and the file name is passed as an argument ($2), so my goal is to get the command within the bash to look something like below:

```
sed -i -e 2,$rows_per_filed $2
```

Now since the **d** is appended to the a variable, it's not doing what it's supposed to do and rather becomes a varialbe **$rows_per_filed**. Any suggestions how I can separate the variable name from the character d in this script?

Comment: `sed -i -e 2,${rows_per_file}d $2`

Comment: Exactly, to the problem "Now since the d is appended to the a variable, it's not doing what it's supposed to do and rather becomes a varialbe $rows_per_filed". The solution is to be use ${} in naming the variable